# Can I edit an XML file based off the result of an IF ELSE statement in Netmiko?

Tags: python, xml, networking, automation, netmiko

Wondering if this is possible. Lets say I am running this function against a cisco iosxe switch using netmiko...

```
Output= net_connect.send_command('show run')
if "logging buffered" in Output:
  print ("logging buffered is configured")
else:
  print ("logging buffered is not configured")
```

Is there a way I could edit an xml document based on the result of that function?

There is a section in an XML file that says

```
<STATUS>Text</STATUS>
```

Can I edit the "text" section based on the output of the if else function?

Also want to add that there are multiple Text areas that would need changed, so could I specify a specific one to edit with each function that I run? wasn't sure if I could specify a location in the xml file to edit?

Thanks

Comment: Xpath can be used to address specific elements. Questions are encouraged to provide a [mcve] and this seems to be more about editing an XML file regardless of the source of information.

Comment: What???????????